# error when copying worksheet into activeworkbook

Tags: excel, temporary-files, file-not-found, vba

I am facing some problems when copying some worksheets from another file into my active worksheet.

The code I am currently using is as follows:

```
        With Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\templates\" & etype & ".xlsx").Worksheets("template")
            .Copy After:=Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
            .Name = result
            .Parent.Close savechanges:=False
        End With
```

It works most of the times but every now and then - and all is done the same way - sometimes I click ten times on the same button and it works but at the eleventh time - it throws the following error:

> File not found: '{AppData_DIR}\Local\VBCDAE.tmp'

Can somebody help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`VBCDAE.tmp` is a temporary file which is locked. And apparently it's not a workbook.

Comment: hm ok but what does this mean - can it be that it closes the file too quickly?